# export individual posts to text files or a single csv file

Tags: database, mysql, sql, export, text

I'd like to export my blog posts to plain text files so I can version control and update them using emacs org-mode via the [org2blog](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog) package.  However, I'm unfamiliar with SQL and the wordpress database structure.  I'm hoping to get ideas for a SQL script to export my posts where each post is stored to a file named "YYYY-MM-DD_Title-of-post.org" and where the files will look like:

```
#+POSTID: 1071
#+DATE: [2011-09-21 Wed 18:00]
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil todo:nil pri:nil tags:nil ^:nil TeX:nil 
#+CATEGORY: cat1, cat2, cat3
#+TAGS: tag1, tag2, tag3
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+TITLE: Hello World
### URL: http://...

BODY OF POST
```

The parts to be filled in is the DATE field, CATEGORY, TAGS, TITLE, URL, and BODY OF POST.

I think it might be asking too much to have someone do all my work for me.  So, alternatively, I'd be content with a SQL script that outputs those fields in a delimited file, say delimited by "|||" so I can write a script elsewhere to get what I want.

Thanks for your help.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting my posts to xml (an option in wordpress) and using the [org2blog-importer](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog-importers) tool that was just created by the author of [org2blog](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog) to get the files into the format I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress plugin repository has several "export to CSV" plugins available. For example [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/navayan-csv-export/) looks interesting. Its also a good startpoint if you don't want to use a plugin and code this on your own.